# How to specify PathToSubformControl for BrowseTo in access 2010

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, vba

Could someone help me with BrowseTo macro plsease? I cannot figure out one of the arguments in the this macro in ACCESS 2010 which is *PathToSubformControl*. I have this Form called "frm_navigation":
[image]

The names of all Tab are: nav_vacancies, nav_contacts, nav_organizations etc.
The field "Organization name" in the figure will hold the name from another table tbl_organizations. However, the Tab "Organizations" (the third from left) will display all info from the table tbl_organizations.

I would like to program a button that takes me to Organization Tab and set a current record according to the name displayed in the field "Organizations name".

So far I did it via DoCmd.OpenForm but it filters out all other records and opens a new window. I tried to set BrowseTo action as follows:

```
    DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "frm_Organizations", "frm_navigation.nav_organizations", "[tbl_organizations].[PR_ID]=" & Me.cb_org_name.Value
```

but I've got runtime error as my PathToSubformControl is wrong. How am I supposed to specify the path? I cannot understand the structure. It's supposed to follow this pattern: MainForm1.Subform1 > Form1.Subform1 but it's not explained what is what.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very late reply, but...

In your code, **"frm_navigation.nav_organizations"** needs to specify the name of the NavigationSubForm subform control (by default it is NavigationSubForm).

Let me try to re-state your command with generic names:

```
DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "frmToDisplayInNavSubCtl", "frmMainFormContainingNavSubFrmCtl.NavSubFrmCtl", ....criteria....
```

So, in short, you need to go into design view on your frm_navigation form and determine the name of the NavigationSubForm control, not the names of the navigation buttons (e.g., nav_organizations, nav_vacancies, etc.) and use that after the dot, instead of .nav_organizations (the name of the button control).