# How to open a navigation form to a specific tab in MS Access

Tags: database, vba, forms, ms-access, tabs

I am trying to build a main menu which is outside of the navigation form and i want to code my buttons for the main menu form so that go to a specific tabs in the navigation form. I have tried the do Command and open form methods, and mostly many methods shown online but none of them seemed to work. This is my navigation form.

[image]

I thought one way to approach them is to use the tab index numbers but i simply have no idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify PathToSubformControl for BrowseTo in access 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884021/how-to-specify-pathtosubformcontrol-for-browseto-in-access-2010)